enable File upload in webview android Studio
I want to make an application that links with my website, I thought that after I created a webview my application could be used straight away, it turns out I have to enable file uploads, what should I add to my code so that it can be enabled
Onboard.java
package com.example.railway;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class Onboard extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    private ProgressBar progressBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_onboard);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(view.GONE);
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("http://172.16.16.9/cmms");
    }
}

manifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.railway">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/logomtn"
        android:label="Cmms Kayaba"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/logomtn"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Railway">
        <activity
            android:name=".Onboard"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

onboard.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />


</RelativeLayout>

I tried search online and watching youtube but it didn't match with my code

To enable file uploads in a WebView, implement a WebChromeClient with onShowFileChooser to manage file selection. Ensure AndroidManifest.xml has the appropriate permissions for Internet and external storage access. Update your activity's onActivityResult to handle file selection results and pass them back to the WebView.
